# Azure recognizeText returns empty result

Tags: azure, ocr

I have been using the OCR API for a while now, but I would like to see if the recognizeText API improved performance. The issue is that calling the recognizeText API just returns an empty string.

If I change the API call to /vision/v2.0/ocr then everything works great.

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'MYAPIKEY',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'mode': 'Printed',
})


with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data_image = f.read()


try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('canadacentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/vision/v2.0/recognizeText?%s" % params, data_image, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Comment: What is your _question_? Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Please do read the API specification: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200

The API only returns 202-Accepted (if your request was valid). This includes a header *Operation-Location* which contains an URL. You make subsequent requests to that URL to retrieve the status / result of your request.